# If I write a string literal in a block, will the entire string data be copied from data section?

Tags: c++, virtual-memory, string-literals

For example,

```
{ // local stack frame C
     cout << "AAAAA" << endl;
     cout << "AAAAA" << endl;
     cout << "BBBBBBBBBB" << endl;
     cout << "BBBBBBBBBB" << endl;
}
```

Here, two strings (string A with size 6 and string B with size 11) are created in the data section at compile time.
And if i write a string literal in a block like above,
the strings A and B in the data section are copied by two into the local stack frame C at compile time.
so 6 * 2 + 11 * 2 = 34.
A total of 34 bytes will occupied the local stack memory.

Is it correct that I understood?

Comment: The code doesn't do anything, which means the compiler could just optimize the whole thing away.  This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Fixed the code situation.

Comment: No, nothing like it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings are not copied to the local stack frame. Instead you are just passing a pointer to the string literal with static storage duration to `cout <<`. Since this pointer has fixed value at compile-time it is also unlikely to occupy any stack memory when compiled.

Stack frames are also usually defined per-function, not per-block.

If you compile the block you are showing as a function with optimizations enabled, then it will probably not use any stack space for local variables or temporaries.